# Specman e: How to constrain 'all_different' to list of structs?

Tags: constraints, specman, e

I have `my_list` that defined this way:

```
struct my_struct {
    comparator[2] : list of int(bits:16);
    something_else[2] : list of uint(bits:16);
};
...
my_list[10] : list of my_struct;
```

It is forbidden to `comparators` at the same index (0 or 1) to be the same in all the list. When I constrain it this way (e.g. for index 0):

```
 keep my_list.all_different(it.comparator[0]);
```

I get compilation error:

```
*** Error: GEN_NO_GENERATABLE_NOTIF: 

    Constraint without any generatable element.
    ... 
    keep my_list.all_different(it.comparator[0]);
```

How can I generate them all different? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also works in one go:

```
keep for each (elem) in my_list {
  elem.comparator[0] not in my_list[0..max(0, index-1)].apply(.comparator[0]);
  elem.comparator[1] not in my_list[0..max(0, index-1)].apply(.comparator[1]);      
};
```

Answer (score 2):

When you reference `my_list.comparator` it doesn't do what you think it does. What happens is that it concatenates all `comparator` lists into one bit 20 element list. Try it out by removing your constraint and printing it:

```
extend sys {
  my_list[10] : list of my_struct;

  run() is also {
    print my_list.comparator;
  };
};
```

What you can do in this case is construct your own list of `comparator[0]` elements:

```
extend sys {
  comparators0 : list of int;
  keep comparators0.size() == my_list.size();
  keep for each (comp) in comparators0 {
    comp == my_list.comparator[index * 2];
  };
  keep comparators0.all_different(it);

  // just to make sure that we've sliced the appropriate elements
  run() is also {
    print my_list[0].comparator[0], comparators0[0];
    print my_list[1].comparator[0], comparators0[1];
    print my_list[2].comparator[0], comparators0[2];
  };
};
```

You can apply an `all_different()` constraint on this new list. To make sure it's working, adding the following constraint should cause a contradiction:

```
extend sys {
  // this constraint should cause a contradiction
  keep my_list[0].comparator[0] == my_list[1].comparator[0];
};
```